# Not getting the functionality of outlined button in ThumbUpAltIcon in Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mern

[image: Image 1] [image: Image 2]

I wish to add the button in the first image as when as person likes a post and the later one when a person unlikes a post and that's how it should work, but I am getting the first image button in both the cases. Please guide me, it would be a great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MUI icons come with many variants for you to choose. You can search for the icons and select which variant you like from [here](https://mui.com/components/material-icons/).

[image]

Based on the screenshots, you'd most likely want the outlined variant for the disable state and the filled variant for the enable state:

```
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import ThumbUpIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ThumbUp";
import ThumbUpAltOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ThumbUpAltOutlined";
```

```
const [like, setLike] = React.useState(false);

return (
  <IconButton color="primary" onClick={() => setLike((x) => !x)}>
    {like ? <ThumbUpIcon /> : <ThumbUpAltOutlinedIcon />}
  </IconButton>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the previous answer, "ThumbUpAltOutlinedIcon" does not exist for MUI, it only exists in the previous version (material-ui). If using "MUI", one should use "ThumbUpAlt" and "ThumbUpOffAlt".